# Mercurial set interface=curses only for crecord alias, leaving record to use interface=text

Tags: mercurial

I'm used to using the legacy crecord extension for Mercurial. I've just upgraded to Mercurial 4 and this extension no longer works, as it's now built-in (as `commit -i`).

However, you only get the curses interface if you specify `[ui] interface=curses`. But this also causes `hg record` to use the curses interface, which is not what I want.

I would like `hg record` to use `interface=text` and `hg crecord` to use `interface=curses` so that I can easily choose between the interfaces like I could before. There doesn't appear to be an option for this. I tried setting the alias to use `--config interface=curses` but it doesn't allow this:

> abort: error in definition for alias 'crecord': --config may only be given on the command line

How can I have aliases for both interfaces?

Comment: `[alias] foo = !hg --config ui.interface=curses whatever`?